# Canvas - flip half the image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, image-manipulation

I have some image data in canvas, and now I need to take the left half of the image, flip it and apply it to the right, like a mirror effect.

**Example**, from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I got this far (I have the image data ready):

```
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 960, 540);
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,960,540);
// loop through the data and apply mirror ??
```

Width & height is known. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Loop through the image data
2. If the current pixel is in the left half of the image, copy it to a position on the right:

```
for(var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(var x = 0; x < width / 2; x++) { // divide by 2 to only loop through the left half of the image.
        var offset = ((width* y) + x) * 4; // Pixel origin

        // Get pixel
        var r = data[offset];
        var g = data[offset + 1];
        var b = data[offset + 2];
        var a = data[offset + 3];

        // Calculate how far to the right the mirrored pixel is
        var mirrorOffset = (width - (x * 2)) * 4;

        // Get set mirrored pixel's colours 
        data[offset + mirrorOffset] = r;
        data[offset + 1 + mirrorOffset] = g;
        data[offset + 2 + mirrorOffset] = b;
        data[offset + 3 + mirrorOffset] = a;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should (More-or less) work, or at least give you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Looks good, but there is something wrong here. The resulting image looks twisted, as if the offset is not correctly calculated.

Comment: @David: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, that site's blocked from here, @David -.- Could you try http://imgur.com/ ? :P

Comment: @David: Ah, how silly of me! I forgot that each pixel takes up 4 "slots" in the data array, so the offset will have to be `pixels * 4`. Edited the answer. I see some colour change, that might be due to the offset being a small bit off. (You might need to add a small int)